# How to fix Key Error in Python using Beautiful soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am having trouble with the following code. I want to extract of every product the title, the URL, the image URL and product number. And extract the data into an Excel spreadsheet.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://b2b.pmsinternational.com/search/?q=&submit=Search+Product+Name'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

items = soup.find_all('section', attrs={'class': 'products'})

rows = []
columns = ['product title', 'Item Number', 'Product URL','Image URL']

for item in items:
    product_url = item.a['href']
    product_image_url = item.a['src']
    product_title = item.a['title']
    product_number = item.a['ref']
    
    row = [product_title, product_number, product_url, product_image_url]
    rows.append(row)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)
df.to_excel('PMS International Products.xlsx', index=False)
    
print('File Saved')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hansm/PycharmProjects/Scraping/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    product_image_url = item.a['src']
  File "C:\Users\hansm\PycharmProjects\Scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1406, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'src'
```

- I have checked the HTML body of the page and I feel like I am addressing the elements properly, but I get that `KeyError` and sometimes the error can change to `href`, `title`, `src`, `ref`.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but I doubt you want to write to file after each iteration. I made an edit in your code above.

Answer (score 1):

The `src` attribute is within an `img` tag that's within the `a`. You need to first `find()` the `img` tag and then access the `src` attribute.

Instead of:

```
product_image_url = item.a['src']
```

use:

```
product_image_url = item.a.find('img')['src']
```

the same goes for `product_title`.
Instead of:

```
product_title = item.a['title']
```

use:

```
product_title = item.a.find('img')["title"]
```

But regarding `product_number`, I don't see a `ref` attribute, hence

```
product_number = item.a['ref']
```

causes an error.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a Key Error because **you are looking for the keys - `src`, `title` and `ref` that are not present in the`<a>` tags**.

- The product URL is present inside the `<a>` tags `href` - *You are getting that right.*
- The product image URL is present inside the `img` tags `src` attribute and not in `a` tags `src` (There is no `src` attribute in `a` tags).
- The product title is present inside a `span` tag with class `title` and not inside the `a` tags `title` (There is no `title` attribute in `a` tags).
- The Item No is present inside a `span` tag with class `ref` and not inside the `a`(There is no `ref` attribute in `a` tags).

Also your code only gets the data of the first product of the web-page. I suppose you need the data of all the products.

Below code will get the data of all products.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://b2b.pmsinternational.com/search/?q=&submit=Search+Product+Name'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

section_products = soup.find('section', attrs={'class': 'products'})
uls = section_products.findAll('ul')


rows = []
columns = ['product title', 'Item Number', 'Product URL','Image URL']

for ul in uls:
    for item in ul.findAll('li'):
        product_url = item.a['href']
        print(product_url)
        product_image_url = item.img['src']
        print(product_image_url)
        product_title = item.find('span', class_='title').text.strip()
        print(product_title)
        product_number = item.find('span', class_='ref').text.strip()
        print(product_number)
```

Comment: How is this provided explanation any different than the one already provided prior to this?